# SharpDevelop: Can you create language plugins for non-.NET languages

Tags: plugins, sharpdevelop

Can SharpDevelop support language plugins for other languages, not just .NET languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharpDevelop can support plugins for other languages other than .Net, in fact [here](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/CPPSupportPage.ashx) is the documentation of an attempt to support C++. However, there are currently no functioning plugins available.